# Pinch zooming out further than minimum in UIWebView using viewport tag

Tags: uiwebview, scale, viewport, meta, pinch

It may sound strange that I am using a UIWebView for this, but for how this project is being put together, I must do this.

I have created a UIWebView which displays an image:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"flatPano" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);    

for (id subview in webView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
```

In my html file, I have a viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5, minimum-scale=1.5, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

In my body I have a simple img tag so the image displays. The initial, minimum and max scale work fine for the most part, but the problem is that I am able to pinch to zoom out *past* the minimum scale, and then I let go, it snaps back into the minimum scale. Cosmetically, this cannot happen as no white background can show.